# It's possible to save a variable position of a list at its own value?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have this list with variables inside:

```
BB= [a, b, c]
```

I want to save in each variable it own position value. My objective its then print one of those variables an get the position.

I tried to do it like this but it doesn't work:

```
le = len(BB)
 for li in range(0,le):
      BB[li]=li
```

Any help or advice will be welcome!

Comment: can you post the required output?

Comment: Objective Output:
a=0
b=1
c=2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the original value you can save tuples with the index :

```
 for li in range(0,len(BB)):
      BB[li]=(li, BB[li])
```

This would output you :

```
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I want to save on the variables its own position number.

Comment: @JuanPabloSilvaSoler It would be inadvisable to define public variables dynamically, you should use a collection (aka. a dict) to store your variables as key and value.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for `globals()`.

**ex:**

```
BB= ["a", "b", "c"]
for i, li in enumerate(BB):
    globals()[li] = i

print(a, b, c)
```

**Note:** it is better idea to create dict and assign values to it.

Comment: Shouldn't you define BB as `BB= [a, b, c]` for this to work?

Comment: I think the OP wants to create variables dynamically.

Comment: @JuanPabloSilvaSoler. `globals()` or `locals()` should help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `globals()` or `locals()`, you can create a dictionary like that:

```
BB = [a, b, c] # assume that `a`, `b` and `c` are hashable
positions = { value: index for index, value in enumerate(BB) }
```

Then, you can access the index as follows: `positions[a]` to get `0`. In order to use a dictionary, you need that the values in your list are hashable, i.e. that they can be used as dictionary keys.